# Zod SafeParse not returning correct success state

Tags: reactjs, zod

I'm building a basic text input that checks to see if a password is valid. The condition is that the password must be 8 characters or longer, and must contain at least one number and special character. Here's the function below:

```
const setPassword = (str:string):void => {
        _setPassword(str);
        const validity = z.string()
            .min(8, {message:"must be 8 characters or more"})
            .regex(new RegExp('.*[0-9].*'), {message: "most contain a number"}) // contains a number
            .regex(new RegExp('.*[@$!%*?&].*'), {message:"must contain a special character"}) // contains a spcial character
            .safeParse(password)
            .success
        _setIsValidPassword(validity)
        console.log(str, validity)
    }
```

Here's the component that's using it

```
<TextField 
    label={'Password'}
    value={password}
    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
/>
```

However, when I test this out, the console logs will go something like this:

$4aaaa false

$4aaaaa false

$4aaaaaa false <--- should be true

$4aaaaaaa true <--- correctly true

$4aaaaaa true

$4aaaaa true <--- should not be correct, below 8 characters

$4aaaa false <--- correctly false

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: I put your exact schema into a code sandbox, and the two values that you say are being parsed incorrectly are being parsed correctly there. (The one you say should be true but is false shows as true for me and the one you say should be false but is true is showing false for me). Are you certain the results you are seeing correspond to the inputs you think they do?

Comment: @Souperman I think I figured it out, it had to do with the way React updates and not Zod. I removed the setValidPassword part from the update function and used a useEffect instead and that solved the problem. Not 100% why React wasn't updating to the latest changes.